How can I set the Cloud Run public port?
I have a Google Cloud Run function, and wish for it to listen on a public port other than 80 or 443, is it possible?
I know I'm able to change the port at the function level, but that only sets the internal port and not the one exposed on the public URL.

Due to load balancing and being a TLS gateway, Cloud Run only supports ports 80 and 443 as public ports.
You are currently unable to change them.
Any internal port customization is meant for hosting containers that have a different hardcoded port number.

Haven't seen that anywhere in the documentation, just something close at the FAQ.
